# Dynamic Element handling

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, dynamic, automation

In our application there is a task view page. For different tasks, xpath for the same button found change every time as below

```
WIN_1_1000000014  
WIN_2_1000000014  
WIN_3_1000000014  
WIN_4_1000000014  
WIN_5_1000000014  

I am providing html codes for two of such scenarios below . I am using following xpaths to find that button but not working for me.
```

**//div[@ardbn='Assignee Organization']//a[@class = 'btn btn3d menu']//img**
 **//img[@alt='Menu for Organization']**

***Help me guys***

```html
<div id="WIN_1_1000000014" class="df arfid1000000014 ardbnAssigneeOrganization Char" arid="1000000014" artype="Char" ardbn="Assignee Organization" arlbox="0,4,78,17" ardcf="1" style="z-index:998;top:84px; left:5px; width:263px; height:21px;" arwindowid="1">
  <label id="label1000000014" class="label f6" for="x-arid_WIN_1_1000000014" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 78px; height: 17px;">Organization</label>
  <textarea id="arid_WIN_1_1000000014" class="text sr " cols="20" maxlen="60" style="top:0px; left:83px; width:154px; height:21px;" armenu="CTM:SGP:SupportOrganization3-Q" mstyle="2" arautoc="1" arautocmb="1" arautocak="0" arautoctt="400" rows="1" title="Service_Desk_First_Tier"
    wrap="off"></textarea>
  <a class="btn btn3d menu" href="javascript:" style="top:0px; left:242px; width:21px; height:21px;">
    <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" alt="Menu for Organization" title="" style="background-color: transparent;">
  </a>
```

```html
<div id="WIN_3_1000000014" class="df arfid1000000014 ardbnAssigneeOrganization Char" arid="1000000014" artype="Char" ardbn="Assignee Organization" arlbox="0,4,78,17" ardcf="1" style="z-index:998;top:84px; left:5px; width:263px; height:21px;" arwindowid="3">
  <label id="label1000000014" class="label f6" for="x-arid_WIN_3_1000000014" style="top: 4px; left: 0px; width: 78px; height: 17px;">Organization</label>
  <textarea id="arid_WIN_3_1000000014" class="text sr " cols="20" maxlen="60" style="top:0px; left:83px; width:154px; height:21px;" armenu="CTM:SGP:SupportOrganization3-Q" mstyle="2" arautoc="1" arautocmb="1" arautocak="0" arautoctt="400" rows="1" title="Service_Desk_Resolver"
    wrap="off"></textarea>
  <a class="btn btn3d menu" href="javascript:" style="top:0px; left:242px; width:21px; height:21px;">
    <img class="btnimg" src="../../../../resources/images/mt_sprites.gif" alt="Menu for Organization" title="" style="background-color: transparent;">
  </a>
```

Comment: What do you mean *not working for me*? Did you get an exception? Share more details

Comment: For 1st task it is working but from 2nd task onwards it is not working.

Comment: If I try to find using IDE  For 1st task xpath is **//img[@alt='Menu for Organization']**  For 2nd task it is **(//img[@alt='Menu for Organization'])[2]**  and so on..

Comment: Without suggesting anything why you making this query as not useful.

Comment: Try this '//div[contains(@id,'WIN_')]'

Comment: Thanks Chandra, But not working

Comment: There is a attribute **arwindowid**. Can I use this in my xpath as a variable.

Comment: Please post a link to the page. Please post the locators you are trying and the exact error message (or why it's not working) for each. Please add all of this to your question rather than putting it in the comments. It makes it harder to find all the info if it's not in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xpath working for 1st 3 elements is
(//div[@ardbn='Assignee Organization']//a[@class = 'btn btn3d menu']//img)[last()]
xpath working for rest elements is
(//div[@ardbn='Assignee Organization']//a[@class = 'btn btn3d menu']//img)[position()<3]

Answer (score 1):

you can write the xpath for the latest task as below:

(//div[contains(@id,'WIN_')])[last()]//img[@alt='Menu for Organization']

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for click or any other operations:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Menu for Organization']"));

        for(int i=1;i<=elements.size();++i){
 elements.get(i).click();
        }
```